# Partial view does't recognize Javascript file that get included in parent

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am using asp .net core 3, I add some multiple partial via javascript

```
function AddBill(type)
        { tag = "....."; // some div and a tags
                $.get('/Glasses/DisplayFarBill?index=' + farIndex,
                            function (partial) {
                                $('#FarSightedBillsSection').append(tag);
                                $('#farSighted' + farIndex).append(partial);
                                $('#farSighted' + farIndex).collapse('show');
                                farIndex++;
                            });
}
```

in main page I include some `js` files that some partial view elements work with that :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/md.bootstrappersiandatetimepicker/dist/jquery.md.bootstrap.datetimepicker.style.css" />
<script src="~/lib/md.bootstrappersiandatetimepicker/dist/jquery.md.bootstrap.datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but when I add partial view with javascript it doesn't recognize that js file, but when I add that partial with code(I mean partial tag ) it will recognize it

I don't want to include it in Partial because I have multiple instances of partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo worked:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult GetPartial()
        {
            return PartialView("_Partial");
        }
        public IActionResult TestPartial()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

_Partial(partial view):

```
<input type="text" data-provider="datepicker" class="datepicker" style="width:200px;" />
```

TestPartial(mainpage):

```
<h1>TestPartial</h1>
<div id="items">

</div>

    @section Scripts{
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/DatetimePicker/dist/datetimepicker.css" />
        <script src="~/lib/DatetimePicker/dist/datatimepicker.js"></script>
       
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                getPartial();
            })
            function getPartial() {
                $.ajax({
    
                    url: '/Test/GetPartial',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (newItem) {
                        $(newItem).appendTo($('#items'));
                        $('.datepicker').MdPersianDateTimePicker({
                            dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                            isGregorian: false,
                            enableTimePicker: true
                        });
                    }
                })
    
            }
    
        </script>
    }
```

result:
[image]

If you cannot recognize it,you can try to use F12 to check `Console`,do you have any error in Console?And check `Network` whether the css and js status is 200?
[image]
[image]

you can put the css and js in _Layout.cshtml like this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: status is 304, and in console It has the error : '$(...).MdPersianDateTimePicker is not a function'. when I include that js file befor 'MdPersianDateTimePicker'  in partial , I have no error

Comment: So you add ` $('...').MdPersianDateTimePicker` in main page?I get the css and js in the [github](https://github.com/Mds92/MD.BootstrapPersianDateTimePicker/tree/master-bs4/dist),and the datetimerpicker css,js status is 304,other status is 200.And it can work.If you still cannot work,you can try to put the css and js into _Layout.cshtml in Shared folder as showing in my answer.

Comment: I used section script as you said in your example, and it worked, thank you, status still is 304 but it works.

Comment: Need other way round. That is parent view to call javascript of partial view. It is saying function undefined. How to do that